# AssemblyInfo Patcher does not update GlobalAssamblyInfo file

Tags: teamcity, assemblyinfo

All our projects are linked to global `assemblyinfo.cs`. I'm using `assemblyInfo Patcher` to update version in `GlobalAssemblyInfo` file (TeamCity 8.1.3), but it works only for regular `assemblyinfo` file that is not global.

Did I missed something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since teamcity 8.1.3, teamcity has extended AssemblyInfo patcher feature to allow patching global assmbly files as well.

[image]